# Run/Toggle command for certain filetypes only

Tags: vim, file-type, autocmd

I found this nice plugin for [distraction free writing named Goyo](https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim), which is really well done.
I setup `autocmds` to enable Goyo based on the filetype, so if I work on a markdown or textfile Goyo gets initialized automatically. If I leave the buffer or change the filetype then Goyo gets closed. Below is how I implemented the behaviour:

```
autocmd FileType * :Goyo!
autocmd FileType markdown :Goyo
autocmd FileType text :Goyo
```

That seems to work fine. The question is, whether or not this is the way to go or if there is a better approach to solve the problem?

Comment: So I tried exactly the same thing and got 
```
Error detected while processing function lightline#update_disable:
line    1:
E121: Undefined variable: s:lightline
```
I'm running lightline as well, do you know any possible fixes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just fine and how I would implemented it, too. As you only hook into the `FileType` event, the toggling is only triggered when you `:edit` a *new* file, not when you recall an existing buffer with another filetype. You could do that with `BufWinEnter`, but it may cause too many inadvertent togglings. I guess the plugin comes with a quick toggle mapping to manually do this, anyway.

#### Alternative

An alternative to the `autocmd FileType` commands is *filetype plugins* (i.e. `~/.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim` etc.), which have the benefit of separating things neatly. But as you need a catch-all autocmd to turn off Goyo, and the list of filetypes is small, I would also prefer keeping things together, just like you did.

#### Improvements

Note that your set of commands would add a duplicate set of autocmds if you re-`:source` your `~/.vimrc` (or whichever script you've put them in). To avoid that, you could wrap them in

```
augroup AutomaticGoyo
    autocmd!
    ...
augroup END
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you review! Good that you pointed me to `augroup` I almost forgot it since I was absent from vimscript for a while. :)